# Generalizing a for-loop in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, for-loop

I don't really know how to describe my issue, so I'll just show a code example:

```
int[][][] mat;
int n;
int specificValue;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(mat[i][n-i][3] != specificValue) {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

I'm looking up Integer values in a 3d-array. For each field I have to use one of these:

- a counter running from zero to n
- a counter running from n to zero
- a fixed value

So i've tried to build a Method that would save me from writing this for loop about 20 times, but i failed, so that's where i need help. My idea was something like this:

```
search(Loop.UP, Loop.DOWN, Loop.FIXED);
```

where "Loop" would be an enum representing one of my possibilities, but I don't know how to implement it or if this is even possible in Java without hardcoding every possible combination.

Hope you can help :)

---

OK, more specific... with my setup i'm drawing a vector through this 3d-array, a diagonal to be specific and i want to know what values are on this vector and **only** on this vector.

And because there is more than one possibility to draw such a vector, i'd like to have a more general method to get to the values. My search could just be as simple as

```
search(Loop.UP, Loop.FIXED, Loop.FIXED);   // one plane
```

which would be a simple for-loop with one counter, but also

```
search(Loop.DOWN, Loop.UP, Loop.UP);   // through all three planes
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about exactly what you want? You want to be able to specify which type of index you use for each field at runtime instead of compile time?

Comment: Can you just have (UP, DOWN) and (DOWN, UP), or all four combinations?  And how many fixed values?

Comment: Can you please provide more examples of how this code snippet might vary across the "20 times"? If it always involves n,i,specificValue in some sort of way, you can omit Loop.FIXED, and replace it with specificValue, you can pass in a `int[] counter1 = new int[] { value1, value2 } - then in your function body you can check if value1 < or > value2 to decide if it's a Loop.UP or Loop.DOWN implicitly.

Comment: The right way to do this would be by implementing your own [Iterator‌​](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).  That's only valid if `doStuff` does not modify the values compared.  Does it?

Comment: doStuff() does not do anything in coherence with this code snippet

Comment: that is one big dangerous array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Path pathX = new Path.Up();
Path pathY = new Path.Down(n);
Path pathZ = new Path.Fixed(3);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(mat[pathX.pos(i)][pathY.pos(i)][pathZ.pos(i)] != specificValue) {
        doStuff();  
    }
}
```

where

```
public interface Path {
    public int pos(int i);

    public static class Up implements Path {
         @Override public int pos(int i) { return i; }
    }

    public static class Down implements Path {
         private int n;
         public Down(int n) { this.n = n; }
         @Override public int pos(int i) { return n - i - 1; }
    }

    public static class Fixed implements Path {
         private int v;
         public Down(int v) { this.v = v; }
         @Override public int pos(int i) { return v; }
    }
```

I didn't use an Enum because `Down` depends on `n` and `Fixed` on some value.

Comment: @Klamann I made an edit: (n - i)    ->     (n - i - 1)   otherwise you'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list of indices. In Python, it could look something like this:

```
LOOP_UP = 20
LOOP_DOWN = LOOP_UP + 20
LOOP_FIXED = LOOP_DOWN + 20

def indexesOfLoopType(loopType, val):
    if loopType == LOOP_UP:
        return range(val)    
    if loopType == LOOP_DOWN:
        return range(val, 0)
    return [val] * val # make a list [val, val, val... ] of length val

def search(loopFirstIndex, loopSecondIndex, loopThirdIndex):
    # use indexesOfLoopType() to get lists of indexes
    # use those lists to iterate over mat
```

Comment: hm, not a bad idea, but making a list of ascending integers just to iterate over another list seems pretty creepy to me.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of at the moment is this:

```
static final int UP = -2, DOWN = -1;

static void loop1(int[][][] A, int t1, int t2, int t3) {
    switch (t1) {
    case UP:
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
            loop2(A[i], t2, t3);
        break;
    case DOWN:
        for (int i = A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            loop2(A[i], t2, t3);
        break;
    default:
        loop2(A[t1], t2, t3);
    }
}

static void loop2(int[][] A, int t2, int t3) {
    switch (t2) {
    case UP:
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
            loop3(A[i], t3);
        break;
    case DOWN:
        for (int i = A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            loop3(A[i], t3);
        break;
    default:
        loop3(A[t2], t3);
    }
}

static void loop3(int[] A, int t3) {
    switch (t3) {
    case UP:
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            // Do something with A[i] here, such as...
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
        break;
    case DOWN:
        for (int i = A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Do something with A[i] here, such as...
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
        break;
    default:
        // Do something with A[t3], such as...
        System.out.println(A[t3]);
    }
}
```

`FIXED` is the only option which requires an index, and is thus encoded as an index. `UP` and `DOWN` are not indices, so they are encoded using negative numbers. Usage would go something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][][] m = { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };
    loop1(m, DOWN, 1, UP);
}
```

With my `System.out.println` example, the output would be

```
7
8
3
4
```

Comment: can you explain that more detailed? i don't really get what these functions should do.

Comment: hmm, I don't think this would work. I need the resulting values of each step at the same time, so i can make a lookup in the matrix instantly. Anyway, this task will be executed very frequently and has to be real fast therefore. Guess I'll just have to hardcode it... 
but thank you very much for your effort!